# Finding a string from list of objects

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have a list of strings and list of objects(SomeObject). Every SomeObject will have a list of other objects(SecondaryObject) and that object will have a string property. I need to check if the string property is in the first list.

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("String1", "String2"));

List<SomeObject> objectList;

public class SomeObject {

    public List<SecondaryObject> secondaryList;

}

public class SecondaryObject {

    public String str;

}

    for (String mainString : stringList) {
      for (SomeObject obj : objectList) {
          List<SecondaryObject> secobjList = obj.getSecList();
          for (SecondaryObject secObj : secObjList) {
              if (secObj.str.equals(mainString)) {
                  log.log("Found a match");
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Is there any optimal solution than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to make use of hashing. Make a hashMap of stringList then you don't need a third loop. Instead for every secObj's string property just try to get it's value from map, if it does'nt return null then your match is found.

```
 HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

 for(String mainString: stringList){
      map.put(mainString, 1); 
   }

 for (SomeObject obj : objectList) {
      List<SecondaryObject> secobjList = obj.getSecList();
      for (SecondaryObject secObj : secObjList) {
          if (map.get(secObj.str) != null) {
              log.log("Found a match");
          }
      }
 }
```

From O(n^3) reduced to O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure if the string property inside any SecondaryObject is unique across the list of SecondaryObject inside SomeObject then I would suggest starting by collating that String in a Set.
The goal is to transform this problem of finding the intersection of two lists of strings.

Then this problem can be solved in two ways

1. Iterate through the stringList and search for that string in the other list. If you sort that list first the searching can be faster
2. This is an optimization to approach 1 where you both the lists and then use the longest common subsequence algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)

Comment: I need to get the secondary object for which a match is found.

Comment: Ok, so that means you can assume that the strings are unique. A simpler approach would be to create a HashMap<String, SecondaryObject> and just lookup for the key in the HashMap